# How to delete replace in a word that have been repeated three or more times

Tags: python, string

I am working with text data for pre-processing. The letters of some words are repeated and I have to correct them.

For example the following sentence:

```
sentence = 'likeeeee sooooo looovvve hmmmmmmm'
```

Must change to:

```
sentence = 'like so love hm'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You may want to read [ask]. You could use a regular expression for this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex and lookaheads, like this. Feel free to ask any questions and I'll try my best to help.

```
import re

s = 'likeeeee sooooo looovvve hmmmmmmm'
print(re.sub(r"(.)(?=\1)","",s))
```

Comment: I had accepted this solution, but now rejected because it changes for example `process` to `proces`

Comment: To the algorithm, the double s is a mistake. If you want the program to not reject it, it will need to understand english words, so you would need to compare the words to a list of words from a dictionary.

Comment: "To the algorithm, the double s is a mistake." Which algorithm?. I said three or more times.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
import re

sentence = 'likeeeee sooooo looovvve hmmmmmmm'

for m in re.findall(r"(\w)\1{2,}", sentence):
    s = m + m
    while s in sentence:
        sentence = sentence.replace(s, m)

print(sentence)
```

Output

```
like so love hm
```